# Display errors and warnings in an org-mode code block

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, python

I would like to be able to report warnings and errors when evaluating a Python code block in an Org file.

When a code block has Python syntax errors, Org helpfully pops them up in a separate buffer called `*Org-Babel Error Output*`.  It would be nice to be able to send my own warnings there too, while retaining the ability to return an array result to Org mode as a table using `:results value`.

To be clear, here is a dummy example of the kind of thing I thought might work:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python 
    import sys
    sys.stderr.write('Warning.\n')
    sys.stderr.flush()
    return [['Table', 'header'], ['table', 'data']]
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
| Table | header |
| table | data   |
```

Edited to add: This [discussion on the org-mode list](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2012-03/msg00048.html) suggests that error output is only displayed when the code-block evaluation fails.  So it looks like this is possible, but only by aborting the evaluation using `exit(1)` or similar.

Comment: Constantine's answer  works perfectly for me, if it is also a solution for you please accept the answer, if it isn't update your question, please.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As described by Eric Schulte on the `org-mode` mailing list (see the link in the question) we can modify `org-babel-eval` to achieve this:

```lisp
(defvar org-babel-eval-verbose t
  "A non-nil value makes `org-babel-eval' display")

(defun org-babel-eval (command query)
  "Run COMMAND on QUERY.
Writes QUERY into a temp-buffer that is processed with
`org-babel--shell-command-on-region'.  If COMMAND succeeds then return
its results, otherwise display STDERR with
`org-babel-eval-error-notify'."
  (let ((error-buffer (get-buffer-create " *Org-Babel Error*")) exit-code)
    (with-current-buffer error-buffer (erase-buffer))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert query)
      (setq exit-code
        (org-babel--shell-command-on-region
         command error-buffer))

      (if (or (not (numberp exit-code)) (> exit-code 0)
              (and org-babel-eval-verbose (> (buffer-size error-buffer) 0)))
      (progn
        (with-current-buffer error-buffer
          (org-babel-eval-error-notify exit-code (buffer-string)))
        (save-excursion
          (when (get-buffer org-babel-error-buffer-name)
        (with-current-buffer org-babel-error-buffer-name
          (unless (derived-mode-p 'compilation-mode)
            (compilation-mode))
          ;; Compilation-mode enforces read-only, but Babel expects the buffer modifiable.
          (setq buffer-read-only nil))))
        nil)
    (buffer-string)))))
```

Now if `org-babel-eval-verbose` is set to `t`, output printed to stderr during evaluation of a source code block show up in a separate window just as if source code evaluation failed.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution based on [Capturing-stderr-from-Python-in-org-mode-take-2](https://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2014/12/21/Capturing-stderr-from-Python-in-org-mode-take-2/):

```
(setq org-babel-python-command "python -i -c \"import sys;sys.stderr=sys.stdout\"")
```

But there are 2 issues:

1. this for some reason doesn't work with `:session` header argument.
2. there is an empty line before and after the result text block.

Comment: I've been struggling with "Unexpected Indent" errors. I'm not 100% sure it's caused by this approach, but I think it might be.