# Catching warnings from sh source block

Tags: org-babel

I've started on Learn C The Hard Way and want to collect my work in org mode. Executing

```
rm ex1 && CFLAGS="-Wall" make ex1
```

in the terminal returns

`cc -Wall    ex1.c   -o ex1
ex1.c: In function ‘main’:
ex1.c:3:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘puts’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   puts("Hello world.");
   ^~~~`

but executing the source block

`+BEGIN_SRC sh :results output :dir lcthw/
  rm ex1 && CFLAGS="-Wall" make ex1
+END_SRC`

renders

`+RESULTS:
: cc -Wall    ex1.c   -o ex1`

without the warnings.

Anyway I can include the warnings in the results of the source block? It is very relevant for working with C.

Feel like I have tried most (all?) results flags without success. Also looked into [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2952/display-errors-and-warnings-in-an-org-mode-code-block), but it specifies as python specific, so not sure if it should work.

Comment: Is there a way for me to improve the question to make it more compelling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :results output :dir lcthw/
  exec 2>&1
  rm ex1 && CFLAGS="-Wall" make ex1
  :
#+END_SRC
```

There are some other options described at http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2015/01/04/Redirecting-stderr-in-org-mode-shell-blocks/, that may be more appealing. This worked for me.

Comment: I've picked up lots of useful things from scimax, but I hadn't seen that before.