# org-babel python code block - not showing errors during execution

Tags: org-babel, python, error-handling

I have a python code block in an org-file that when executed results in some error. I was expecting to see that error in the `#+RESULTS:` block, but it doesn't show up. I have to navigate to the python session buffer in order to see whether the evaluation was successful. More over, when a previous code block is unsuccessful, and the next code block depends on it's results, I can continue executing code without any indications that evaluation is failing (except for missing output).

How can I configure org-babel to display such errors/exceptions in the `#+RESULTS:` block?

## How to reproduce

I have this property set at the top of my org file

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args :session my_py_session
```

### Sample block

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python
r = some_function_which_results_in_a_trace_back()
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC python
x = r*2
#+END_SRC
```

When I do a `C-c` on both these blocks, Emacs reports something like `Code block evaluation complete (took 0.5 secs)` in the mini buffer.

But when I open the python session buffer, I see this error. How can I get this error to show in the `#+RESULTS:` block?

```
>>> 
org_babel_python_eoe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 17, in __PYTHON_EL_eval
  File "/var/folders/7k/r1g1zhmx16gbtm1hbllhhk_w0000gs/T/py3Fvne8", line 18, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'some_function_which_results_in_a_trace_back' is not defined. Did you mean: 'NameError'?
>>> 
org_babel_python_eoe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 17, in __PYTHON_EL_eval
  File "/var/folders/7k/r1g1zhmx16gbtm1hbllhhk_w0000gs/T/pywWfEwY", line 8, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'r' is not defined
```

## What I already tried

- Tried redirecting sys.stderr to sys.stdout
- Tried this: [Display errors and warnings in an org-mode code block](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2952/display-errors-and-warnings-in-an-org-mode-code-block)
- Explicitly try-catching works, but is very tedious to do for every block

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output
try:
    r = some_error()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: name 'some_error' is not defined
```

Comment: FYI, you will get it when using python via [emacs-jupyter](https://github.com/emacs-jupyter/jupyter)